# Identification of the organic compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, alcohols, chirality, organic-oxidation

> An organic compound **A** $(\ce{C10H14O})$ exhibits following characteristics.
>
> A) It reacts with metallic sodium to give a colorless odorless gas.
> B) It is oxidized by $\ce{KMnO4}$ to benzoic acid.
> C) It can be resolved.
> D) It does not give precipitate with iodine in presence of $\ce{NaOH}.$
> E) It changes the color of acidified potassium dichromate from orange to bluish
> green, and gives a chiral compound.
>
> How many of the following compounds satisfy all the five criteria from A to E?
>
> [image]

The given answer is the compounds **4**, **5**, **10** satisfy the criteria but I think the compounds **5**, **6**, **12** satisfy the criteria.

From statement A, we come to know it's an alcohol (which is common to every compound).

From statement B, we come to know that it has a benzylic hydrogen (which rules out the compound **11**).

From statement C, we come to know that it has a chiral carbon. (which rules out options **4**, **7**, **9**).

From statement D, we come to know that $\ce{OH}$ group is not attached to a methyl group (which rules out options **3**, **10**).

For statement E, I guess potassium dichromate will oxidise 2° alcohol to ketone and 1° alcohol to carboxylic acid and the compound still remains chiral (which rules out options **1**, **2**, **8**).

So where's the mistake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that correct answer should be 5 and 6 only, because:

- 12 will produce [terephthalic acid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terephthalic_acid), instead of benzoic acid as it possess two benzylic-H (also given by 7).

[image: terephthalic acid]

- 4 and 10 doesn't satisfy statement C and D, as you've mentioned.

Comment: I agree; the answer given is clearly incorrect. 4 and 10 fail the criteria

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't notice the extra methyl group in 12 :).

Answer (score 10):

The given answer is wrong in many ways:

- **4** did not satisfy both criteria C and E, because it is not a chiral compound to begin with.
- **10** did not satisfy the criteria D, because it does give a precipitate with iodine in presence of $\ce{NaOH}$.

That gives only **5** in given answer to satisfy all criteria. Let's eliminate given compounds in systematic order:

[image: eliminate given compounds according to criteria]

That leaves only **5** and **6** to satisfy all criteria.

Comment: How do you know that #3 and #10 precipitate?

Comment: @Stanislav Bashkyrtsev: **3** and **10** are oxidized by $\ce{I2}$ to give methyl ketones first, which give positive idoform test.

Comment: @ Mathew Mahindaratne, why don't the carbanion form at the benzylic carbon, and react further giving a negative iodoform test

Comment: @Govind: Can you elaborate your question a bit? I didn't understand your angle.

Comment: I think 10th should also be in the answer and should satisfy condition D. As the carbanion intermediate formed while iodoform test would be more stable at benzylic carbon

Comment: @Govind: Compound $\bf{10}$ will give a precipitate with $\ce{I2/NaOH}$ not because your reason. First, $\ce{I2/NaOH}$ oxidizes $2^\circ$-alcohol to ketone, which would be a methylketone, satisfying the condition for iodoform test.

Comment: @ Mathew Mahindaratne It is not necessary that all methyl ketones give iodoform test. Take for instance Methyl acetoacetate